# How to include case class body members in Play Json Writes?

Tags: scala, play-json

I have:

```
sealed trait MessageType { def description: String }
object MessageType {
  case object Important extends MessageType { override val description = "important" }
  case object Normal extends MessageType { override val description = "normal" }
}

trait Message { def messageType: MessageType }

case class SomeMessage(from: String, to: String, text: String) extends Message {
  override val messageType: MessageType = MessageType.Important
}

object SomeMessage {
  implicit val someMessageWrites: Writes[SomeMessage] = (
    (JsPath \ "from").write[String] and
    (JsPath \ "to").write[String] and
    (JsPath \ "text").write[String]
  )(unlift(SomeMessage.unapply))
}
```

Then using `Json.toJason(someMessage)` will produce Json with the `from`, `to`, and `text` fields, but I also want to have a field `messageType` with a value of "important".

I could include the message type field as a constructor parameter, but that seems like a hack - the message type field should be fixed, not specified.

Is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: Replace `unlift(SomeMessage.unapply)` with your custom function that's `SomeMessage => Tuple4`.

Comment: JSON handler automatically generated by the Macros are only based on the properties, aka what's considered in the appy/unapply mechanism. If you want something more custom, you have to provide a custom handler (not a generated one).

Comment: Thanks. Both these comments were helpful. I replaced `unlift(SomeMessage.unapply)` with `(message) => (message.messageType, message.from, message.to, message.text)`. If one of you would make your comment an answer, I will mark it as the accepted answer.